# Function not returning the pyspark DataFrame

Tags: python, function, dataframe, pyspark

I have defined a function which returns a dataframe of intersection of all dataframes given as the input. However when I store the output of the function in some variable, it won't get stored in the variable. It is shown as a nonetype object

```
def intersection(list1, intersection_df,i):
    if (i == 1):
        intersection_df = list1[0]
        print(type(intersection_df))
        intersection(list1, intersection_df, i+1)
    elif (i>len(list1)):
        print(type(intersection_df))
        a = spark.createDataFrame(intersection_df.rdd)
        a.show()
        return a
    else:
        intersection_df = intersection_df.alias('intersection_df')
        tb = list1[i-1]
        tb = tb.alias('tb')
        intersection_df = intersection_df.join(tb, intersection_df['value'] == tb['value']).where(col('tb.value').isNotNull()).select(['intersection_df.value'])
        print(type(intersection_df))
        intersection(list1, intersection_df, i+1)
```

e.g if I give the input as following,

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
list2 = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
list3 = [6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,4,16,343]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(list1, StringType())
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(list2, StringType())
df3 = spark.createDataFrame(list3, StringType())
list4 = [df1,df2,df3]
empty_df = []
intersection_df = intersection(list4, empty_df, 1)
```

I expect the following output to be stored in interesection_df

```
 +-----+
 |value|
 +-----+
 | 7   |
 | 11  |
 | 8   |
 | 6   |
 | 9   |
 | 10  |
 | 4   |
 | 12  |
 | 13  |
 +-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got hit by the curse of recursion.

Problem:
You are calling `intersection` recursively but returning only in one of the if condition. So when it returns your df, it has no where to go (recall: each function call creates a stack).

Solution:
return when you call `intersection` from your `if` and `else` condition. for ex `return intersection(list1, intersection_df, i+1)` in your `if` condition.